# I got the first size working but can't set the size for my other constructors

Tags: c++, templates, copy-constructor, default-constructor

How would I make my template header find the size of all myvecs the first is set for zero if there is no constructor it works but I don't know how to have the 10 be set for myvecB the size. The 5 be set for myvecC size. The 6 be set for myvecD size.

main.cpp

```
int main()
{
 myclass<int> myvecA;
 myclass<int> myvecB(10);
 myclass<int> myvecC(5,-9);
 myclass<string> myvecD(6, "Hi");

 cout << "A size: " << myvecA.size() << endl;
 cout << "B size: " << myvecB.size() << endl;
 cout << "C size: " << myvecC.size() << endl;
 cout << "D size: " << myvecD.size() << endl;
system("Pause");
return 0;
}
```

My template class

```
#include<iostream>

template <class C>
 class myclass{

public:
 myclass(int x);{
    sizearr = x;}

 explicit myclass() : sizearr(0) {}

 V size();

private:

 V sizearr;

};

template <class V>
 V myclass<V>::size() {
   return sizearr;
}
```

Comment: What is `V` shouldn't that be `int`?

Comment: Is it `myclass` or `vector`? That's how your "MCVE" loses all credibility.

Comment: That code doesn't compile. Use copy and paste.

Comment: Your class is missing a 2-parameter constructor, so `myvecC` and `myvecD` cannot be constructed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you showed is full of errors and does not compile.  Try this instead:

```
template <class V>
class myclass {    
public:
    myclass() : sizearr(0) {}
    myclass(int x) : sizearr(x) {}
    myclass(int x, const V &v) : sizearr(x) {}

    int size();

private:    
    int sizearr;    
};

template <class V>
int myclass<V>::size() {
    return sizearr;
}
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    myclass<int> myvecA;
    myclass<int> myvecB(10);
    myclass<int> myvecC(5, -9);
    myclass<string> myvecD(6, "Hi");

    cout << "A size: " << myvecA.size() << endl;
    cout << "B size: " << myvecB.size() << endl;
    cout << "C size: " << myvecC.size() << endl;
    cout << "D size: " << myvecD.size() << endl;
    system("Pause");
    return 0;
}
```